# AJAX with POST and GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Will this be a legitimate call for AJAX to handle?
I pick up the `$_GET` variable, but not the `$_POST`.
The '*selected*' is a array of data from a `dataTable` selection.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: './inc/MediaScripts.php?argument=deleteRecords',
        type: 'POST',
        data: selected
    });
```

**Server side** `print_r($GLOBALS);`

> ```
> [_GET] => Array
>     (
>         [argument] => deleteRecords
>     )
>
> [_POST] => Array
>     (
>     )
> ```

.

**Updated:**

**Edited JQuery**

> ```
>         $.ajax({
>             url: './inc/MediaScripts.php?argument=deleteRecords',
>             type: 'POST',
>             data: { "test1": "value1", "test2": "value2" }
>         });
> ```

**Result**

> ```
> [_GET] => Array
>     (
>         [argument] => deleteRecords
>     )
>
> [_POST] => Array
>     (
>         [test1] => value1
>         [test2] => value2
>     )
> ```

Comment: @AntoKing, funny... its the first sentence. (maybe why you say yes or no will be helpfull as-well).

Comment: I understand you have php on server side?

Comment: Yes. sorry, should probably include that in the description down stairs.

Comment: ` I pick up...` I assume then you can see the call itself is working?

Comment: You should be able to receive the data like that, have you tried to insert static data just to see if it works? for example:        `data: { "test1": "value1", "test2": "value2" }`

Comment: Can you display the content of the javascript var: selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data property should look something like this data: {"selected": selected}

other than that if the url is correct just try something like this

```
$.ajax({
   url: './inc/MediaScripts.php?argument=deleteRecords',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {"selected":selected}
}).done(function() {
   alert('works');
});
```

and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

*I pick up the `$_GET` variable, but not the `$_POST`*

I think you should post an object instead:

```
data: {selected : selected}
```

On the server side you can pick this up with:

```
$_POST['selected'] // it contains the array you posted.
```

---

All in all i suggest you to stic with `type:"post"` and pass the vars like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './inc/MediaScripts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {argument:"deleteRecords", selected : selected}
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't he send the request using `type: "POST"` if he wants to read `$_POST` also?

Comment: I think he's trying to access both the `POST` & `GET` data.

Comment: @Darren, Yes, I would like to know if exactly that is possible?

Comment: Sorry guys just misunderstood this, but as i understood now OP is able to pick up the var in url but not the array selected which is sent in ajax and that should be sent with a js object instead.

Comment: @mornenel - Could you update your answer to show what `selected` looks like?

Comment: @Jai, Yes thanks i think that is correct. Just tried a simmilar proposal from user `UnTraDe` and it worked, but I have to use the PostGet approach as its been done like that to access the function serverside. ReWrite needed possibly? Yes, but...

Answer (score 0):

Any data passed in the URL queryString can be accessed with $_GET, even if you use *POST* to submit the data, but the 'data' ('selected' array) can only be read in the $_POST variable.

Comment: Sorry but this answer makes **no** sense what-so-ever. You're stating the obvious here..?